# razor add class if condition is false

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Hey i need to add class to div only if count is higher than 6  but i dont know where is the problem. Thanks for any advice

```
                @{
                    int count = 0;
                 }
                @foreach (var item in Model.Models)
                {
                    <div class="col-xxs-12 col-xs-6 col-sm-4 @(count < 6 ? "" : "dismiss")">
                        <a href="@Url.Action("Detail", "Product", new { productID = item.ProductID, parentCategoryID = item.CategoryID, isProductModel = true })" class="model-wrap">
                            <div class="box">
                                <div class="img-wrap" style="background-image: url( @Url.Content(Utils.ProductImagePath(item.ImageID)) )"></div>
                                <div class="arrow f16">@item.Name <i class="fa fa-angle-right theme-color" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                } count++;
            </div>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your problem here is "count++" is not in foreach loop. 
If you want to use foreach loop you should move "count++" inside loop.

```
       @{
            int count = 0;
        }
        @foreach (var item in Model.Models)
            {
            <div class="col-xxs-12 col-xs-6 col-sm-4 @(count < 6 ? "" : "dismiss")">
                <a href="@Url.Action("Detail", "Product", new { productID = item.ProductID, parentCategoryID = item.CategoryID, isProductModel = true })" class="model-wrap">
                    <div class="box">
                        <div class="img-wrap" style="background-image: url( @Url.Content(Utils.ProductImagePath(item.ImageID)) )"></div>
                        <div class="arrow f16">@item.Name <i class="fa fa-angle-right theme-color" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
            count++;
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

**Regarding Setting Your Class**

Your existing code looks fine as it will only add the dismiss class if your count value is greater than or equal to 6 via your ternary statement :

```
<div class="col-xxs-12 col-xs-6 col-sm-4 @(count < 6 ? "" : "dismiss")">
```

**Scoping Your Iteration**

Have you considered using a `for` loop, which will automatically handle storing the current index for you? This might make keeping track of the count a bit easier and resolve any possible issues with your counter not being scoped properly (as `count++` is outside of your `foreach` loop):

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Models.Count(); i++)
{
    // Store a reference to your item to ease syntax
    var item = Model.Models.ElementAt(i);
    <div class="col-xxs-12 col-xs-6 col-sm-4 @(i < 6 ? "" : "dismiss")">
      <a href="@Url.Action("Detail", "Product", new { productID = item.ProductID, parentCategoryID = item.CategoryID, isProductModel = true })" class="model-wrap">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="img-wrap" style="background-image: url( @Url.Content(Utils.ProductImagePath(item.ImageID)) )"></div>
            <div class="arrow f16">@item.Name <i class="fa fa-angle-right theme-color" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
        </div>
      </a>
  </div>
}
```